# Ejercicio programación - Rango Switch Notas

Tags: java

Escribe un programa que permita introducir una calificación (entre cero y diez) e imprima su equivalente alfabético, según la siguiente tabla.

Menor 3 -------> M.D.

Desde 3 y menor que 5 -------> INS.

Desde 5 y menor que 6 -------> SUF.

Desde 6 y menor que 7 -------> BIEN

Desde 7 y menor que 9 -------> NOT.

Desde 9 hasta 10 -------> SOB.

Si no tuviera decimales sabría hacerlo, pero no se poner un rango en el case.Sin decimales lo haría así.

```
System.out.println("Dime una nota: ");
        float x = leer.nextInt();

switch (x) {

            case 3:
                System.out.println("MP");
            case 5:
                System.out.println("SUF");
            case 6:
                System.out.println("BIEN");
            case 7:
                System.out.println("NOT");
            case 9:
                System.out.println("SOB");
```

Comment: utiliza la sentencia if else en vez de switch case y podrás hacerlo sin problema!

Comment: De hecho, a tu `switch` le faltan `break`s para que funcione bien, y considerar casos como el `4`. Tienes dos opciones, con `if` o bien convertir los `float` a `int`

Comment: Si utilizas `leer.nextInt()` por qué lo almacenas en un `float`?

Comment: Encontrarás maneras ingeniosas de hacer un control condicional semejante con switch en [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873590/using-switch-statement-with-a-range-of-value-in-each-case) en Stack Overflow en inglés, pero ninguna es mejor que utilizar sentencias if-else if, porque el código más legible suele ser el mejor código.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí te muestro una posible solución. Esto metodo te permite analizar un valor entre los rangos de interes.

```
public String calificacion(int nota){
    String resultado = "";

    switch(nota){
        case 0: case 1: case 2: // si la nota < 3
            resultado = "M.D.";
            break;
        case 3: case 4:         // si la nota >= 3 && < 5
            resultado = "INS.";
            break;
        case 5:                 // si la nota >= 5 && < 6
            resultado = "SUF.";
            break;
        case 6:                 // si la nota >= 6 && < 7 
            resultado = "BIEN.";
            break;    
        case 7: case 8:         // si la nota >= 7 && < 9
            resultado = "NOT.";
            break;
        case 9: case 10:        // si la nota >= 9 && < 10
            resultado = "SOB.";
            break;
        default:                // para cualquier otro valor no valido
            resultado ="No valido";
            break;
    }

    // respuesta obtenida de acuerdo a la valoración de la nota
    return resultado;
}
```

Comment: siempre debes agregar una explicación, revisa [answer] considera que debe ser entendible no solo para quien preguntó sino para el resto de usuarios

Comment: @AndyC sacarse un 9 y 10 es insuficiente ? ,Revisa el código.